# Uncaught TypeError: sel.add is not a function

Tags: javascript, function, addition, html-select

1. HTML with select tag:

   ```
   <select id="sel"></select>`
   ```
2. here in JavaScript part, I am trying to add options in select dropdown creating them inside for loop assigning array values to option:

   ```
   var sel = document.getElementById('sel').value;
   var jsonobj = {School_charles: {class_A: [{ idkey: "1", name: "john" },
                 { idkey: "2", name: "jill" }]}};

   for(var i = 0; i <= jsonobj.School_charles.class_A.length; i++) {
       var option = document.createElement('option');
       option.text = jsonobj.School_charles.class_A[i].idkey;
       option.value = jsonobj.School_charles.class_A[i].name;
       sel.add(option);    
   }
   ```

Please tell me where I am wrong, I am learning JavaScript.

Comment: var sel = document.getElementById('sel').value;
must mbe var sel = document.getElementById('sel');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two mistakes in your code:

1. `var sel = document.getElementById('sel').value;` should be just `var sel = document.getElementById('sel');` so the the variable `sel` references the actual select element instead of the select value. That is the reason the `add()` method was not recognised.
2. Your for loop condition should be only `i < jsonobj.School_charles.class_A.length` and not `<=`

```js
var sel = document.getElementById('sel');
var jsonobj = {
  School_charles: {
    class_A: [{
      idkey: "1",
      name: "john"
    }, {
      idkey: "2",
      name: "jill"
    }]
  }
};

for (var i = 0; i < jsonobj.School_charles.class_A.length; i++) {
  var option = document.createElement('option');
  option.text = jsonobj.School_charles.class_A[i].idkey;
  option.value = jsonobj.School_charles.class_A[i].name;
  sel.add(option);
}
```

```html
<select id="sel"></select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Two mistakes there

- `document.getElementById('sel').value` should be `document.getElementById('sel')`
- `i <= jsonobj.School_charles.class_A.length` should be `i < jsonobj.School_charles.class_A.length`

```js
var sel = document.getElementById('sel');
var jsonobj = {School_charles: {class_A: [{ idkey: "1", name: "john" },
              { idkey: "2", name: "jill" }]}};

for(var i = 0; i < jsonobj.School_charles.class_A.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.text = jsonobj.School_charles.class_A[i].idkey;
    option.value = jsonobj.School_charles.class_A[i].name;
    sel.add(option);    
}
```

```html
<select id="sel"></select>
```